# How can I rewrite a subdomain to go to a specific file in a specific folder?

Tags: apache, htaccess, redirects

I've done searching for my answer and have tested a few solutions, but nothing has worked so far.

I'm trying to get a URL like this `http://baseball.sports.com` to rewrite to `http://pro.sports.com/baseball-index.php`.

However, I still need to keep the domain the same (`http://baseball.sports.com`). The reason being I have about 5 subdomains (`baseball`, `football`, `soccer`, etc.) that I want to run off the same code base (`pro.sports.com`).

Everything is on the same server. I'd be happy to answer any other questions that would help me get a resolution.

I truly appreciate any direction that can be given to me to solve this.

Comment: What are the solutions you have tested already but didn't work?

Comment: Where is the webroot for `baseball.sports.com` and `pro.sports.com`? Are they the same directory?

Comment: if your directory structure on hosting is like `/home/username/pro/ (for pro subdomain)` and `/home/username/baseball/`, you can use same code on any domain by including source from real path.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should ask your host about Wildcard

https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Wildcard_Subdomains
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to create an *index.php* and place it in your web root folder (normally named *public_html*) that is connected with the website `http://baseball.sports.com`.

That *index.php* file must contain a script to load contents from the other website you're trying to link to.

This PHP code might work well for you:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("http://pro.sports.com/baseball-index.php");
?>
```

If not, then you should research the CURL library, especially if the other website involves secure forms you want users to fill in, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rules won't work across sub-domains, even on the same server.

You could use mod_proxy to make this happen.  Configure baseball.sports.com to proxy the information that you want from the other subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something pretty similar to me.

This code worked (it redirects the user to a new link) but it needs some polish

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1-index.php [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

So this should redirect someone entering to "baseball.example.com" to example.com/baseball-index.php

Best regards

PS: Credits to Dave Lozier ([Redirect subdomain to folder without changing the URL](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81923/redirect-subdomain-to-folder-without-changing-the-url))